# How to install Brother Printer MFC-L2740DW

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, printing

I am using Lubuntu, and I wanted to connect [my printer](http://support.brother.com/g/b/producttop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcl2740dw_us_eu_as), to my computer. But I followed the commands given by the brother company, but I was unable to make that work, because I wanted the wireless approach of it. For that I need the device URI, but I clicked auto for that, and that worked, but the installation of the device didn't work.

Comment: please post the exact steps you followed.

Comment: I used this [link](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcl2740dw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625)

Comment: Did you specify device _URI_ ?

Comment: I clicked the auto one, as I didn't really know what the other options were for.

Comment: You should not have as the instructions states that you should provide a __URI__ please remove and try again, this time follow it step by step.

Comment: How would I find the device URI

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, from the date, you are using 16.04? After I upgraded Lubuntu to 18.04, I successfully installed an MFC-2740DW simply by using the System Tools>Printers>+Add option, selecting Network Printer.
It found my printer. Upon selection, it offered three protocols to communicate with the printer. I chose the 'Driverless ...' option and hit 'Forward'. It then went looking for a driver[this is the 'driverless' option, remember ...], found it, and added the printer. Perhaps upgrading to 18.04 is the solution?

Comment: Did you have problems using your printer in 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

This post pertains only to 22.04, as I was having the same problem after I upgraded the OS.

When asked if you will specify the URI, answer "Yes".

Enter the numerical option for specifying the I.P. address.

When entering the I.P., use the complete format as is shown in the "Network" menu of your printer, i.e; 192.168.001.123. Do not abbreviate the I.P. address as, 192.168.1.123.

This is where I found my error, and my scanner now functions again as it should.